# ConvexHull orders differently in matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab, convex-hull

I have this problem: I need to use in my Python code the `ConvexHull` function and I need it to work exactly the same way as the `ConvHulln` in MATLAB, but they give different results. This is an example (I'm using the `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` but I've tried with the `cv2.convexHull` and with the Python [`ConvexHull`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhull) too and they don't give the correct result.

The MATLAB command used is: `k = convhulln([r, c]);` and the Python command used `k = ConvexHull(rc,qhull_options='Qt').simplices`

The results obtained are different:

MATLAB:

```
k= 
[[104 1] [1 8] [8 17] [17 103] [103 125] [125 136] [136 162] [162 166] [166 167] [167 163] [163 104]]
```

Python:

```
k=[[ 16 102][103   0][  7   0][  7  16][162 166][162 103][124 102][124 135][161 135][165 166][165 161]]
```

The results are right (in Python the index is MATLAB-1), but the order is different. Does anyone have a solution for that? I need Python's order to be the same as MATLAB's order.

Comment: Have you considered using an algorithm that doesn't depend on the order of the points, as there is ***no natural/intrinsic ordering present in a convex hull***?

Comment: do you know any draw polygon algorithm in Python that doesn't depend on the order of points? Because when I draw the polygon in Matlab (poly2mask) and Python with the different order of points given by the convexHull it returns different images.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is your problem 2d? The [docs of `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) demonstrate that "*We could also have directly used the vertices of the hull, which for 2-D are guaranteed to be in counterclockwise order:*" (see first example there). It might help if you add two figures: one from matlab, one from python.

Answer (score 0):

Meet a similar problem in 3D Convexhull. 
My walk around is sort according to the indices 
Also, the Matlab convex hull is orientation consistently, however, the python one is not. So you shall also check whether the normal of each face is consistent with the convex hull.euqations[:,[1,2,3]], rearrange the index order so each face's normal is consistent, then we will have the exact same face order.

For 2d, I think the difference is the starting point. I believe Matlab always starts with the minimal index.